How to incorporate sources of observational error in state space model?
I’m learning about state space models. I understand the concept of a latent process that is unobserved, and a noisy set of observed data that we can use to estimate the latent process. I am trying to find some clear examples (ideally with code) of where covariates with a known impact on observation error have been included in the model.
For example, if one is estimating fish populations, then it’s reasonable to assume that weather will impact the measurement and will be a source of observation error. If I log the weather every time I measure the population, how do I incorporate that into my model?
Another example – maybe I am measuring weight for citizens of a city over time. I ask everyone which neighborhood they live in, and at the end I see that I have fewer samples for a neighborhood than I would expect for some neighborhoods and more than I would expect for others given the total population of each.
Perhaps even over time – maybe my study started years ago and I didn’t have much traction in getting volunteers, but the study became more popular over time and I was able to gather more samples this year than I was last year even though the size of the population didn’t change.
All of these are sources of observation error, no? How could I include that information in a state space model? Or if there is a good “cookbook” with examples then that would be helpful, too. I’m comfortable with R or Python and happy to read Bayesian models built in Stan, PyMC, etc.

"If I log the weather every time I measure the population, how do I incorporate that into my model?" --- depending on how it's set up, regression-type predictors should be able to be incorporated into the model. The unknown parameters can be treated as part of the state, for example.
